# Git adds empty files instead of folders

Tags: git

Project structure: ecommerce > ecommerce-back (contains folders and files), ecommerce-front (contains folders and files)

I'm trying to commit everything in ecommerce directory by using `git add .` however the folders (ecommerce-back and ecommerce-front) are being committed as empty files instead of folders which contain more folders and files.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: What operating system and version of git you are using; are those directories real directories or just symlinks?

Comment: I'm using windows and version is ```git version 2.22.0.windows.1``` . They are real directories. @blami

Comment: Do you have anything in `.gitignore` file(s)? If not; after committing those directories do you see files in those directories in `git log --name-only --oneline` output? (you can also add `-n 1` to show just latest commit)

Comment: I suspect that you have, in your work-area, multiple separate Git repositories. The `ecommerce` level has one Git repo and the `ecommerce-back` and `ecommerce-front` sub-directories / folders each *also* have one Git repository. Your top level `ecommerce` Git is therefore trying to use the other two repositories as *submodules*.

Comment: If that's what you want, use `git submodule add` to add them correctly as submodules. Otherwise you get these half-assed submodule entities that you're seeing. But if that's not what you want, don't do that.